# Function getResult call

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working transferring my functions from MySQL to MySQLi standards.

This is my old function for getresult

```
  function getResult($sql) {
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
            if ($result) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                die("SQL Retrieve Error: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
```

However, I have been following the W3schools on the mysqli_query function. Here's where I'm presently at.

```
 function getResult($connection){
        $result = mysqli_query($connection->conn);
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            die("SQL Retrieve Error: " . mysqli_error());
        }
    }
```

Now, the examples on W3schools are just a bit different from how I want to use mysqli_query. I'm trying to make it be directed at my DB, not some input or constants as per examples on W3S.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cad\func.php on line 92

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cad\func.php on line 92

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cad\func.php on line 96
SQL Retrieve Error:
```

Thank you

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Yes, the getresult function isn't working as intended. Should have put some errors in here.

Comment: so please proceed, improve your question as needed

Comment: Done - see edit. Apologies.

Comment: [mysqli.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) -> `mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version won't work for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that you haven't included the query you want to send. Assuming $this->conn is set up properly somehow, try this:

```
 function getResult($sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);  //Note parameters reversed here.
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            die("SQL Retrieve Error: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP help files I found these function definitions

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )
```

mysqli_query() takes the link and the actual query as mandatory parameters, and mysqli_error takes the link as one as well.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php